# SD card problem when Downloading

Tags: updates, sd-card, insufficient-memory

I recently updated my Nokia 3 system to android 8,  I have a space of 5 GB in my SD card and 6 GB internal. I had been using my SD card as internal storage before I updated my system. But now with that free space of 11GB ( 5GB SD card and 6GB internal, I can't download songs from SNAPTUPE , it indicates that "there's no enough space in the SD card, free up your space" what could be the problem, and how can I solve it out without interfering with the data already in my SD card. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure, you have checked the correct partition for free space. Use an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) to check all partitions.